# How to manage the root and the user folder when using a personal machine

Tags: root, account, user-accounts, administrator

I hope this question fits into this forum. I've just started using Ubuntu and realized the difference between root(Administrator) and user. But I'm having trouble managing files between these two separate directories.

For example, when installing python Anaconda, I usually install it in C:\ since it is much easier to access it compared to installing in my user folder. Not to mention most of the programs are installed in C:\ or in program files, so just putting Anaconda there makes it easier to remember its location.

This got me thinking, I cannot think of any reasons for separating the root and the user folders when using the computer alone. It only seems to make managing the files more complex. I have found that separating them makes it easier to fix things (separate mount points etc) in Linux, but what about in Windows?

So here is my question; what is the benefit of separating the two directories even when using the machine by oneself only (even in Windows)? What are some of the tactics or best practices to manage files between the two directories without making it too difficult to find the desired files one wants?

This might be a basic question but I couldn't find satisfactory answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Unix, dot not run as root for regular use. Just don't do it. As far as keeping files separate, software on Linux is usually installed to globally accessible folders like /usr/bin, /usr/local, /opt, etc. The software configuration files can be set globally, but can also be overridden locally (per user). Google about Unix filesystem layout and user management an you may find more relative information.

Comment: @mrunion Thanks, that will help me going through this Linux stuff.

Comment: Running as an admin user on Windows is a mistake. It means that everything that runs under your account pretty much has the ability to do anything (and that would include any hacker or malware that made it onto your machine). It also encourages poor coding and security habits. Not a good idea to do so just because you're feeling too lazy to do things right. You don't leave your doors and windows wide open when going on vacation just because it's too much work to close and lock them, do you?

Comment: @KenWhite Then do I have to use an account with a lower privilege and use the Administrator account whenever need arises? I'm feeling the impression that this is what Linux does. Maybe I just have to play with Linux more then I'll have a better understanding of how things should work.

Comment: Yes. You use a non-admin account for everything, providing admin credentials when prompted for them by UAC when you're doing something (and when you understand why they're being requested, like when changing Windows settings or installing software). As far as *nix goes, any decent tutorial will explain why you never run as root, even if you're the only user of the machine. It's much easier to start off right than it is to have to rebuild a machine because you've bricked it by running something destructive as root because *nix knows that a root user won't make a mistake. :-)